# C# Visual Studio give String was not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do a college project in C# and .Net where i need to scrape the number of likes from a page using Facebook API and plot a graph.

However, the code below works perfectly fine in Visual Studio Express 2013 (Windows 8.1) but when I try to run it in Visual Studio 2010 (Windows 7), it gives the error String not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The program uses .NET Framework Version 4.0

Please help, the code is given below

```
    int GetNumberOfLikes(string strGraphUrl,string strUrl)
    {
        int number_of_likes = 0;
        object value = "";            
        string jsonString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(strGraphUrl);
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer obj1 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> objDic = (Dictionary<string, object>)obj1.Deserialize<object>(jsonString);
        Dictionary<string, object> likeCount = (Dictionary<string, object>)objDic[strUrl];
        bool success = false;
        success = likeCount.TryGetValue("likes", out value);
        if (success)
        {
            number_of_likes = (int)value;
        }
        return number_of_likes;
    }

    void WriteToTextFile(string strFileName,int number_of_likes)
    {
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + strFileName;

        string strToday = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString();
        strToday = strToday.Substring(0, 10);
        string strLikes = strToday + ":" + number_of_likes.ToString();
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(strLikes);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string line;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

            Boolean containsToday = false;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line.Contains(strToday))
                {
                    containsToday = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    containsToday = true;
                }

            }
            sr.Close();
            if (containsToday == false)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(strLikes);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Which .NET framework version are you targeting?

Comment: strToday = strToday.Substring(0, 10); what are you trying to do here?

Comment: There is a a login script in the same page where we need to enter facebook api number and auth code. after that it connects to facebook apges already specified and collects the data and then this code where the date is taken and the clustered likes number is plotted against the graph according to date in the format DD MMM YYYY for example 21 Mar 2015 will have 100 likes, 22 Mar 2015 will have 200 likes and the graph goes higher and so on. 

The error occurs upon loggingin in Visual Studio 2010, but not in Studio express 2013 thats why I was confused.

Comment: @GrawCube version 4.0

Comment: Are you sure the raw json being returned is the same in both cases?

Comment: I think you wanna break out, of your while loop when you set containsToday = true. Otherwise you only check if the last line in the file contains today. As for the error you are getting. On what line doest it occur?